# How to insert values from textfields into database in java

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jdbc, jtextfield

I want to insert values from jtextfields into my database. but following error is occured..  Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'employee' any solution?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class DataEntry implements ActionListener{  
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

       //  Database credentials


            //Create and set up the window.
           JFrame mainframe=new JFrame("Database Operation");
           JPanel mainpanel=new JPanel();
           JButton insertbtn=new JButton("Insert");
           JButton viewbtn=new JButton("View");
            JLabel label1=new JLabel("ID: ");
           JLabel label2=new JLabel("Age: ");
           JLabel label3=new JLabel("");
           JFrame insertframe=new JFrame("Insert into Database");
           JPanel insertpanel=new JPanel();
           JLabel idlabel=new JLabel(" id");
           JTextField idtext=new JTextField(20);
           JLabel agelabel=new JLabel(" age");
           JTextField agetext=new JTextField(20);
           JButton insertsubmit=new JButton("Submit");
           JFrame viewframe=new JFrame("View Database Data");
           JPanel viewpanel=new JPanel();
           Vector datacol=new Vector();
           Vector datarow=new Vector();
           JTable datatable;
           JScrollPane viewdata;

           public void init()
           {
            mainwindow();
            }
           public void mainwindow()
           {
             mainpanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            mainpanel.setLayout(null);
            insertbtn.setBounds(300, 300, 100, 30);
            viewbtn.setBounds(800, 300, 100, 30);
            mainpanel.add(insertbtn);
           mainframe.add(mainpanel);
            mainframe.setSize(1350, 700);
            mainframe.setVisible(true);
            insertbtn.addActionListener(this); }  
           public void insertwindow()
           {
           insertpanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
           idlabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
           agelabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

           insertpanel.setLayout(null);
           idlabel.setBounds(400, 150, 100, 20);
           idtext.setBounds(550, 150, 150, 30);
           agelabel.setBounds(400, 200, 100, 20);
           agetext.setBounds(550, 200, 150, 30);

           insertsubmit.setBounds(490, 300, 100, 30);

           insertpanel.add(idlabel);

           insertpanel.add(idtext);
           insertpanel.add(agelabel);
           insertpanel.add(agetext);

           insertpanel.add(insertsubmit);
           insertframe.add(insertpanel);

           insertframe.setSize(1350, 700);
           insertframe.setVisible(true);
           insertsubmit.addActionListener(this);
           insertframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
           {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
             mainframe.setVisible(true);
            }
           }
           );
           }
           public void viewwindow()
           {

            datacol.removeAllElements();
            datarow.removeAllElements();
            OpenDatabase();
            try
            {
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select id,age from employee");
            ResultSetMetaData rms=rs.getMetaData();
            int cols=rms.getColumnCount();
            for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
            {
             datacol.addElement(rms.getColumnName(i));
            }
            while(rs.next())
            {
             Vector row=new Vector(cols);
             for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
             {
              row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
             }
             datarow.addElement(row);
            }
            datatable=new JTable(datarow,datacol);
            viewdata=new JScrollPane(datatable);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Problem in Database connectivity or Data", "Result", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            }
            viewpanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            viewpanel.setLayout(null);
            viewdata.setBounds(20, 50, 1250, 600);
            viewpanel.add(viewdata);
            viewframe.add(viewpanel);
            viewframe.setSize(1350, 700);
            viewframe.setVisible(true);
            viewframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
             {
              mainframe.setVisible(true);
             }
            });}
           public void insertdata(String id, String age)
           {
            try
            {
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("insert into employee values("+id+",'"+age+")");
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your Data Has been Inserted", "Result", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } 
            catch(Exception e)
            {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Problem in Database connectivity or Data", "Result", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
           }
           public void OpenDatabase()
           {

            try
            {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
             System.out.println(e);
            }
           }
           public void CloseDatabase()
           {
            try {
             conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
            }

           }public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

               if(arg0.getSource()==insertbtn)
               {
                mainframe.setVisible(false);
                insertwindow();
               }
               if(arg0.getSource()==viewbtn)
               {
                mainframe.setVisible(false);
                viewwindow();
               }if(arg0.getSource()==insertsubmit)
               {
                   String id=idtext.getText();
                   String age=agetext.getText();

                   try
                   {
                   OpenDatabase();
                  insertdata(id,age);

                   CloseDatabase();

                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                    System.out.println(e);
                   }
                   idtext.setText("");
                   agetext.setText("");}}


                   public static void main(String args[])
                   {
                   DataEntry dm=new DataEntry();
                    dm.init();

                   }
                  }
```

Comment: Use a valid username/password when connecting to the database

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with

```
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee");
```

`DriverManager.getConnection()` ' parameters setting should be like

```
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

If your mysql have default settings and you use root user it should be as

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root", "your password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give user id and password in getConnection method

```
  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee","root","password");
```

"root" as user id of my sql(As in yor system)
and "password" as password of my sql (As in yor system)

Answer (score 0):

Use user name & password of your mysql database in getConnection method

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee");
```

as

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee","root","password");
```